# Cumulative addition of elements to the dictionary

Tags: python

There is an array of numbers and a list of words. A dictionary must be created that contains the new number in each row and the words added cumulatively to each row

For example:
`array of numbers = [5,6,7]` and `list of words = ['a','b','c']`

Expected result:

```
[{'number': 5, 'letter_list:': ['a']}, 
{'number': 6, 'letter_list:': ['a', 'b']}, 
{'number': 7, 'letter_list:': ['a', 'b', 'c']}]
```

I wrote code that works well, but maybe it could be simplified

```
list_ = ['a','b','c']
array_= [5,6,7]

main_list=[]
count_x=0

for x in array_:
    count_x+=1
    
    len_list=len(list_)
    for i in range(1,len_list+1):
        dict_={'number': x, 'letter_list:': list_[0:i]}
        if count_x==i:
            main_list.append(dict_)

print(main_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use index offset of enumerated iteration:

```
d = [{'number': v, 'letter_list:': list_[:i]} 
     for i, v in enumerate(array_, 1)]
print(d)
```

---

```
[{'number': 5, 'letter_list:': ['a']},
 {'number': 6, 'letter_list:': ['a', 'b']},
 {'number': 7, 'letter_list:': ['a', 'b', 'c']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you could get rid of the `count_x=0` and `count_x+=1` since you increase the counter at the very begginning of the loop you might as well use `enumerate`

```py
list_ = ['a','b','c']
array_= [5,6,7]

main_list=[]

for idx,x in enumerate(array_):
    
    len_list=len(list_)
    for i in range(1,len_list+1):
        dict_={'number': x, 'letter_list:': list_[0:i]}
        if idx==i:
            main_list.append(dict_)

print(main_list)
```

Next:
`len_list=len(list_)` could be moved to outsude the first for loop since it won't ever change.

Lastly, you only add `dict_` to main_list if idx (count_x) macthes the current i value, so you don't even need `len_list` and could just:

```py
list_ = ['a','b','c']
array_= [5,6,7]

main_list=[]

for idx,x in enumerate(array_, 1): # start counting at 1
    dict_={'number': x, 'letter_list:': list_[0:idx]}
    main_list.append(dict_)

print(main_list)
```

Edit:

Also, as a side note, you may want to change the variable names to not start or end with underscore, instead if you're using a reserved keyword like `dict` change it to something like `myDict`
dict is not technically reserved like `class`, `global`, `return`, etc... so you can overwrite it and break things.